# How to plot a series of start and end points on a single stacked horizontal bar graph in excel

Tags: excel, vba, plot

want to create a single horizontal stacked bar graph showing the series of start and end points (given). For example, if the data is given as below:

```
From To     Status
1    2      Complete  
2   2.5     Uncomplete
2.5  3.5    Complete
3.5  5      Complete
5    5.7    Uncomplete    
5.7  7      Complete
```

So, if i try to plot above data, then i should be able to draw a single stacked horizontal bar graph from 1 to 7 highlighting the completed sections (1 to 2, 2.5 to 5 and 5.7 to 7). And also the non completed sections like 2 to 2.5 and 5 to 5.5 can also be highlihgted in different colour.
For example, the output may be as below:

1---***2--2.5***---3---4---***5---5.7***---7

How do I plot single stacked horizontal bar graph as above.

Answer (score 1):

Given the above, I would say using the Macro Recorder in your case would give you some idea and you should be able to work off that!

Nonetheless, I have drafted the below:

Given the data set:

[image]

I created a named range for the data, as this is easier to refer to and could make your code more dynamic.

Code to generate the chart:

```vb
Sub CreateStackedColumnChart()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim chart_obj As Object


    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set myRng = ws.Range("myRange")

    Set chart_obj = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked)
    chart_obj.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=myRng

End Sub
```

Giving the below output:

[image]

There is a plethora of content on the web regarding chart manipulation, and I will leave it up to you to research how to edit the chart to the output you need.